# Mutate DOM object without user interaction in AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to make number of views component on page initial load with setInterval but AMP gives an error DOM mutation not possible without user interaction, do we have any workaround for this? i have a component that contains height more than 300px. thanks in advance

number of views component appears in middle of the page so is this possible to manipulate dom object on scroll event, whenever appear element then only show animation with number of views

[playground](https://playground.amp.dev/#share=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)

Comment: Please show your reproducible example and indicate where the mutation fails.

Comment: you can see above playground and have a look console, there you can see errors

Comment: hi @JayGray, have you seen problem, i tried with layout not container but still not work, it's not possible to mutate DOM object on page load or something without user gestures?

Comment: i could not relate your question to the playground example. there are limited non-mutation examples of `amp-script` (e.g. fetch). But, in general, `amp-script` is used to mutate a DOM action bound to a subset of DOM objects.

Comment: Hi @Urock have you tried with layout fixed-height  in amp-script? like this "<amp-script script="hello-world" layout="fixed-height" height="100">"

Comment: yes if we use layout fixed or fixed-height working fine but somehow don't know my content height to make it fixed, one more thing, i have to trigger script whenever scroll position reach element or visible element, still thinking how we achieve this behaviour